# Alarm manager not working without internet connection

Tags: android, connection, alarmmanager

I have scheduled an alarm like this

```
private void startAlarm() {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationBrodcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), 120000, alarmIntent);

}
```

And I have WakefulBroadcastReceiver for it

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intentService = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    startWakefulService(context, intentService);
}
```

In service, I sent coordinates to the server, but the problem is that if I turn the internet connection off, the alarm stops repeating.

Comment: What happened without Internet, a exception happen ? If so, did you release the wakelock Using completeWakefulIntent?

Comment: maybe an exception is thrown which kills the service?

Comment: Can you add the logcat if any? Please.

Comment: Yes, exception thrown in service when no internet connection, but why alarm stops working ?

Comment: You catch the exception and stop the service normally?

Comment: In catch I doing nothing , when is no internet connection, problem is that code in onReceive method of BrodcastReceiver ,not runing  after some time after that.

Comment: What did you do in the service location? Just a start and stop service? I will try a few things

Comment: In service I sent location (coordinates)  to server.